# How should I make a big string of floats?

Tags: python, concatenation

I'm creating an arff file with a lot of numeric data. Now since my feature vector is quite large, I ended up with code like this

```
with(file,'w') as myfile:
    s = number + ","
    s += number + ","
    s += number + ","
    s += number + ","
    ...
    myfile.write(s)
```

Since I'm quite new to Python I obviously forgot about the fact that Python doesn't seem to allow floats to be concatenated to strings like that and giving me the following error.

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.float64' and 'str'
```

So how would a more experienced python programmer deal with this problem or do I really have to cast all those numbers to strings like this

```
with(file,'w') as myfile:
    s = str(number) + ","
    s += str(number) + ","
    s += str(number) + ","
    s += str(number) + ","
    ...
    myfile.write(s)
```

Comment: Also for those reading this, I'd like to thank the SO community. Almost all my previous problems where solved by the first link on google, which was a link to SO ^_^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't write CSV rows by hand. Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
with(file, 'wb') as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerow([number1, number2, number3])
```

Each element in the list is converted to a string for you.

When using `numpy` arrays, you can use [`numpy.savetext()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to achieve much the same results.

Even without the `csv` module, you can just a sequence of values into one string with [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), with a judicious helping of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to make sure all values are strings:

```
s = ','.join(map(str, [number1, number2, number3]))
```

A quick demo of the latter (using Python 2):

```
>>> number = 42.4245
>>> string = 'The quick brown fox'
>>> empty = None
>>> map(str, [number, string, empty])
['42.4245', 'The quick brown fox', 'None']
>>> ','.join(map(str, [number, string, empty]))
'42.4245,The quick brown fox,None'
```